# Errorhandler not called after error SAPUI5 callFunction()

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to validate an IBAN inside of a Wizard in SAPUI5. To do this, I use a `functionImport` on an V2 `ODataModel` (sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel).
The request comes back with a 202 status code but it actually failed.
This is the response (from the Firefox Network tab):

```
--1D57E7CB0DD73AB15048B36CC96993D60
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=1D57E7CB0DD73AB15048B36CC96993D61
Content-Length:         1303

--1D57E7CB0DD73AB15048B36CC96993D61
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Length: 1134
content-transfer-encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 950
dataserviceversion: 1.0
cache-control: no-cache, no-store
pragma: no-cache
content-id: id-1687346500037-256

{"d":{"CheckIBAN":{"__metadata":{"type":"XXXX"},"AccountID":"XXXXXX","IBAN":"DEXXXX","BankID":"","WithInOutPayment":true,"SepaNotifText":"XXX"}}}
--1D57E7CB0DD73AB15048B36CC96993D61--

--1D57E7CB0DD73AB15048B36CC96993D60
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Length: 1111
content-transfer-encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 991
dataserviceversion: 1.0

{"error":{"code":"XXX/076","message":{"lang":"de","value":"XXX"},"innererror":{"application":{"component_id":"XXX","service_namespace":"XXX","service_id":"XXXX","service_version":"0001"},"transactionid":"XXX","timestamp":"XXX","Error_Resolution":{"SAP_Transaction":"XXX","SAP_Note":"XXXX"},"errordetails":[{"code":"XXX/076","message":"XXX","propertyref":"","severity":"error","target":""}]}}}
--1D57E7CB0DD73AB15048B36CC96993D60--
```

(X'ed everything that is confidential)
This is the result in the browser console:
[image: error message in console]
So it has to be registered somewhere.
The code where I registered the callback are the following:

```
this.SERVICE.functionImport("CheckIBAN", XXX.Constants.HTTP_POST, XXX, true, {
            fnSuccess: jQuery.proxy(function (oData) {
                fnCallback(oData);
            }, this),
            fnError: fnError
        });
```

Note that the `functionImport` function is just a wrapper for the [sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.callFunction](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/callFunction) and does the same.
No matter what I enter (a right or wrong input), it always calls the `fnSuccess`.
When I use the `read` function of the `ODataModel` (so just a simple `GET`-request) everything works just fine and it fires the `fnError` when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your question dosen't contain a question "?"

I assume you ask why "error" is not called?

"error" is called if the http request fails. As you use batch, any error within a changesSet is not handled by this API... UI5 v2 is not a very elegant implementation....

see also: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1382#issuecomment-288723906